# Lambda Expression + pySpark

Tags: azure-databricks, pyspark

Am trying to compare a column in spark DataFrame against a given date, if column date is less than given date add n hour else add x hours.

something like

```
addhours = lambda x,y: X + 14hrs if (x < y) else X + 10hrs
```

where y will hold a static date specified then apply on DataFrame column

something like

```
df = df.withColumn("newDate", checkDate(df.Time, F.lit('2015-01-01') ))
```

here is sample for df

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import datetime
df = spark.createDataFrame([('America/NewYork', '2020-02-01 10:00:00'),('Africa/Nairobi', '2020-02-01 10:00:00')],["OriginTz", "Time"])
```

Am bit new to spark dataframes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`when+othewise`** statement instead of `udf`.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

#we are casting to timestamp and date so that we can compare in when
df = spark.createDataFrame([('America/NewYork', '2020-02-01 10:00:00'),('Africa/Nairobi', '2003-02-01 10:00:00')],["OriginTz", "Time"]).\
withColumn("literal",F.lit('2015-01-01').cast("date")).\
withColumn("Time",F.col("Time").cast("timestamp"))

df.show()
#+---------------+-------------------+----------+
#|       OriginTz|               Time|   literal|
#+---------------+-------------------+----------+
#|America/NewYork|2020-02-01 10:00:00|2015-01-01|
#| Africa/Nairobi|2003-02-01 10:00:00|2015-01-01|
#+---------------+-------------------+----------+

#using unix_timestamp function converting to epoch time then adding 10*3600 -> 10 hrs finally converting to timestamp format
df.withColumn("new_date",F.when(F.col("Time") > F.col("literal"),F.to_timestamp(F.unix_timestamp(F.col("Time"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')  + 10 * 3600)).\
    otherwise(F.to_timestamp(F.unix_timestamp(F.col("Time"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')  + 14 * 3600))).\
show()

#+---------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
#|       OriginTz|               Time|   literal|           new_date|
#+---------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
#|America/NewYork|2020-02-01 10:00:00|2015-01-01|2020-02-01 20:00:00|
#| Africa/Nairobi|2003-02-01 10:00:00|2015-01-01|2003-02-02 00:00:00|
#+---------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
```

In case if you don't want to add **literal value** as dataframe column.

```
lit_val='2015-01-01'

df = spark.createDataFrame([('America/NewYork', '2020-02-01 10:00:00'),('Africa/Nairobi', '2003-02-01 10:00:00')],["OriginTz", "Time"]).\
withColumn("Time",F.col("Time").cast("timestamp"))

df.withColumn("new_date",F.when(F.col("Time") > F.lit(lit_val).cast("date"),F.to_timestamp(F.unix_timestamp(F.col("Time"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')  + 10 * 3600)).\
    otherwise(F.to_timestamp(F.unix_timestamp(F.col("Time"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')  + 14 * 3600))).\
show()

#+---------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
#|       OriginTz|               Time|   literal|           new_date|
#+---------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
#|America/NewYork|2020-02-01 10:00:00|2015-01-01|2020-02-01 20:00:00|
#| Africa/Nairobi|2003-02-01 10:00:00|2015-01-01|2003-02-02 00:00:00|
#+---------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using **`.expr`** and **`interval`**. This way you do not have to convert to another format.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("new_date", F.expr("""IF(Time<y, Time + interval 14 hours, Time + interval 10 hours)""")).show()

#+---------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
#|       OriginTz|               Time|         y|           new_date|
#+---------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
#|America/NewYork|2020-02-01 10:00:00|2020-01-01|2020-02-01 20:00:00|
#| Africa/Nairobi|2020-02-01 10:00:00|2020-01-01|2020-02-01 20:00:00|
#+---------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+
```